# log4net custom appender ignore exception

Tags: c#, log4net

I'm trying to programmatically ( in C#) create a rolling file appender. For the pattern layout, I'm trying to set the IgnoresException property, but there is only a getter and not a setter. If I go the web.config route, with the pattern layout info set there, I can set the IgnoresException value. Is this the only way to set this value?

Edit: here is what I'm trying to do:

```
PatternLayout patternLayout = new PatternLayout();
        patternLayout.ConversionPattern = "%d{MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss} - %p - %m%n";
        patternLayout.ActivateOptions();

        RollingFileAppender roller = new RollingFileAppender();
        roller.AppendToFile = true;
        string path = Path.Combine(requestLogFolderPath, GetDateStringFileName());
        roller.File = path + @"\CaptureLogInfo.txt";
        roller.Name = "CaptureLogAppender";
        roller.Layout = patternLayout;


        roller.MaxSizeRollBackups = 5;
        roller.MaximumFileSize = "1MB";
        roller.RollingStyle = RollingFileAppender.RollingMode.Size;
        roller.StaticLogFileName = true;
```

Comment: One thing that I usually do when searching for examples is going over github and check code search (you must be logged in) how ever, you can take a look at https://github.com/search?l=C%23&p=1&q=IgnoresException+log4net&type=Code and see examples on how people implemented it in their project.

Comment: Could you show us your code? LayoutSkeleton and PatternLayout have `get` and `set` properties. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Like I said, there is a `set` in PatternLayout.IgnoresException: `patternLayout.IgnoresException = true;` What's the problem in here?

Comment: It looked like there was only a getter for IgnoresException and not a setter.

Comment: It could be that I'm using an older version of log4net.